# Javascript addeventlistener Event Loop

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown table like this

| A header |
| --- |
| First |
| Second |
| Third |

when user click it, a table open and I will get that item ID

| A header |
| --- |
| First |
| *First item content* |
| Second |
| Third |

The addEventListener used for getting a elementId, then I can fetch the particular URL, but it work only a "click" detected. I want having a addEventListener checking **No click event** ,then I can simulate the click event for updating fetch.

```
const change= document.getElementById("select");
change.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
//stuff
fetch(`www.abc.com/{event.target.id}` )
.then ......
})
```

Can I do it like this?

```
change.addEventListener(!'click', (event) => {
var test =setInterval(loop,40000);    
     function loop()  {              
         change.click()               
     }       
})
```

Comment: A non-click is not a capturable event. What you can do, however, is fire off the loop on an interval, and cancel the interval if the click event happens. Also this seems like an extremely strange solution to a problem I'm not sure exists. Can you please elaborate on what your issue is?

Comment: You might be better of just creating a function for the fetch and calling it from both the click even and on a timer to keep it approximately updated

Comment: your suggestion is good, let me try it. thank you.

Comment: Possible [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)